# How can I use WienerProcess with TimeSeriesForecast?

Tags: plotting, fitting, random, time-series

I created a TimeSeries from Date-Value-Pairs, which I imported from a .csv-File

```
diffp = Import["path/difficultyp.csv", "Data"];

tsdiff = TimeSeries[diffp];
```

I have no problems when I use the inbuild TimeSeriesModelFit function, for example

```
tsdfit = TimeSeriesModelFit[tsdiff, {"SARIMA", 9}];
```

and afterwards create a Forecast with

```
tsdforecast = TimeSeriesForecast[tsdfit, {100}]
```

This works and tsdforecast is of "type" TemporalData. However, I want to use a WienerProcess instead, following [the second example in this doc of EstimatedProcess](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EstimatedProcess.html). What I did:

```
eproc = EstimatedProcess[tsdiff, WienerProcess[a, b], ProcessEstimator ->"MaximumLikelihood"]
forec = TimeSeriesForecast[eproc, tsdiff, {20}]
```

However, this doesn't work and the last line returns not something of "type" TemporalData but just "Out: TimeSeriesForecast[WienerProcess[...],TimeSeries[...], {20}]". When I try to plot the results with

```
DateListPlot[{tsdiff, forec}]
```

I get an error message

```
DateListPlot::ldata: {TemporalData[TimeSeries,{{{82.938,80.878,82.224,81.678,82.534,84.138,84.534,87.76,88.902,90.508,90.111,88.552,82.166,76.928,78.75,82.528,80.947,79.482,78.498,78.996,81.073,79.895,80.591,80.545,87.318,90.096,91.837,93.445,94.534,97.382,98.722,99.096,99.976,101.356,102.517,103.641,104.134,103.817,102.053,107.184,106.857,108.358,108.811,111.109,109.885,110.021,111.654,112.707,111.597,110.677,<<260>>}},<<5>>,{<<1>>}},True,10.3],<<1>>} is not a valid dataset or list of datasets. >>
```

Which probably is a type error. But I can't get my head around this to solve it. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: I'm using 11.2 on Win 7 Ent with `tsdiff  = TimeSeries[FinancialData["NYSE:GE", "Close", {{2000, 12, 31}, {2016, 12, 31}, "Month"}], TemporalRegularity -> True]`. `eproc` does evaluate to a `WienerProcess` but `TimeSeriesForecast` does not cooperate.  You should report to WRI and then report back.

Answer (score 3):

By design `TimeSeriesForecast` supports only time series processes, which are discrete time processes. WienerProcess is a continuous time process. It is stochastic difference equations vs stochastic differential equations.

P.S. Also, `TimeSeriesForecast` is computing conditional mean (future trend) conditioning on data, which makes sense for time series processes with autoregressive components. `WienerProcess` has independent increments.